# Ping multiple host/ips objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, ping, host

I want to get the list of ip's  connected in the same wifi network .

I am manually trying to ping ip range from 0-255 based on my allocated ip address , but it is taking long time to get ping status.  Is there any optimised function library in **objective C or C** for this?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar Sapkale

Comment: Why are you doing that, as it sounds like you are attempting to hack the local LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pinging to the broadcast address or use a multicast socket.

Join a multicast group by first creating a multicast socket with the desired port, then invoking the joinMulticastGroup method.
When a message is send to a multicast group all subscribing members receive the message.

[You can refer to this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459116/how-to-receive-multicast-udp)